# Using foreach loop to find variable POST data

Tags: php, variables, post, foreach

Why doesn't this work?

```
// I'm sending this data: $_POST['amount_1'] = '3';
$val = '1'; // This is coming from a foreach loop, but I'm specifying here for simplicity
echo $_POST['amount_'.$val]; // Returns null
echo $_POST['amount_1']; // Returns 3
```

Are variables not allowed when trying to get a POST value?

**Edit:** Posting more code per request.

```
$outgoing = array();

foreach($_POST as $key => $val):
    if(strpos($key,'_number_')){ // Matching 'item_number_' would return false because of 0-indexing
        $item_id = $val;
        $test = str_replace('item_number_',$key); // Realized when pasting this that I didn't have a $replacement defined.
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity_'.$test];

        $name = $_POST['lp-name'];
        $email = $_POST['lp-email'];
        $phone = $_POST['lp-phone'];

    array_push($outgoing,array($test,$item_id,$quantity,$name,$email,$phone));
    }
endforeach;

$json = json_encode($outgoing);
```

Works now. I didn't have a `$replacement` defined in my str_replace().

Comment: do a var_dump on $val - I'm guessing it might have some whitespace characters in it.

Comment: more code would be good too. :)

Comment: Code you provided looks fine. please post full code.

Comment: echo $_POST['amount_'.$val]; should print 3 as well .... check for other stuff

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this, you can use array notation in form elements:

```
<form>
    <input name='amount[]' value='this is first'>
    <input name='amount[]' value='this is second'>
    <input name='amount[]' value='this is last'>
</form>
```

Submitting this form will send the data in array format:

```
echo $amount[0]; // this is first
echo $amount[1]; // this is second
echo $amount[2]; // this is last
```

Best wishes,

Korvin

Comment: I found that method while searching for my issue today. I'll definitely use it in the future, but this project is for a PayPal cart so I'm locked into their naming conventions.